# How can I know the parameters that I must pass to function?

Tags: node.js

I'm new about node.js and I would understand witch parameters I must pass to function. For example in some functions I can pass Request,response, error and in other function I must pass other things. Anyone can suggest me some tutorials or gives me some advices?

Comment: A well configured IDE ***may*** (or may not) help. Welcome to weakly, dynamic typed languages

Comment: see this stackoverflow  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045889/good-editor-for-node-js) for eclipse support for javascript. Here is the [link](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vjet-javascript-ide).